# Angular 4.x Scopes ( Restrict ) for Custom directives

Tags: angular

Is scopes and Restrict attributes for creating custom directives are available In angular 4.x like AngularJS 1.X ?.

I tried searching in angular docs & googled some blogs i was not able to find?.

can any body please clarify is this ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no controllers in Angular unlike AngularJS. Angular is component based thus you should change the way you think entirely with Angular.

`scopes` and `restrict` directives on AngularJS are the following in Angular.

Angular uses `this` instead of `$scope` and anything that is within a component class can be accessed on the html template. Read more about Angular component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Angular uses `selector` instead of the `restrict` option. Read more about Angular directives https://angular.io/api/core/Directive